# Shiny server/UI file does not render the desired output - Logs not helpful

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app file as follows. I am receiving the error "An error has occured. Check your logs or contact the app author." I cannot figure out what is wrong. What is in the log file makes no sense to me either:

```
processing file: index.Rmd
Quitting from lines 8-43 (index.Rmd) 
Warning: Error in tag: argument "label" is missing, with no default
  150: tag
  149: tags$button
  148: actionButton
  137: eval
  136: eval
  131: evaluate_call
  130: evaluate::evaluate
  129: evaluate
  127: block_exec
  126: call_block
  125: process_group.block
  122: process_file
  121: knitr::knit
  120: <Anonymous>
  115: <reactive>
   99: doc
   98: shiny::renderUI
   97: func
   84: origRenderFunc
   83: output$__reactivedoc__
    3: <Anonymous>
    1: rmarkdown::run
```

Here is the file content. I would like to have two drop-down inputs which specify which two columns of data we are interested in. We then display a two-way contingency table (frequency analysis) for those two columns.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Frequency Analysis"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = "course1",
                  label = "Choose a course:",
                  choices = c("CS125", "CS173", "CS225", "CS374")),

      selectInput(inputId = "course2",
                  label = "Choose a course:",
                  choices = c("CS125", "CS173", "CS225", "CS374")),

    ),

    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("tableOut"),
      tableOutput("tableOut")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  courseInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$course1,
           "CS125" = CS125,
           "CS173" = CS173,
           "CS225" = CS225,
           "CS374" = CS374
           )

    switch(input$course2,
           "CS125" = CS125,
           "CS173" = CS173,
           "CS225" = CS225,
           "CS374" = CS374
    )
  })

  output$tableOut = renderPrint({
    data = read.csv(file = 'FourCourseTableLetterGrades_POLISHED.csv', sep = '\t')
    tbl = table(data$input$course1, data$input$course2)
    tbl
  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you put a Shiny app in `index.Rmd`?

Comment: Just add a label to your `actionButton` and the error will be resolved (e.g. `actionButton(inputId = 'test', label='test')`)

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren thanks, but now I only see the left sidebar and no table in the main panel. Do you know why?

Comment: @JohnCoene I thought that was the structure of one of the sample apps. Example 3 at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html

Comment: `data$input$course1` and `data$input$course2` is not valid code. Also what is the RHS here `"CS125" = CS125`?